# How to Store the HTML Datatype Value In Database using Sugarcrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM, We create one new Field With the data type as HTML.

After Creating this type of field it's not created in the database.

Please Suggest me how to add HTML Type value in database

[image]

Comment: HTML fields aren't stored in the database. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: but we want to store this value into the database. t is possible or Not

Comment: What value? HTML fields in SugarCRM are rendered on the screen, so I'm confused as to what exactly you plan to store. If you can elaborate as to what you're trying to achieve, there might be another way.

Comment: have you trying to store that value using the module loader in form of packages.

Comment: What I do for that